# Request for Assistance with Ubuntu 22 Pro Audit Tool Issue

Tags: server, 22.04

I'm trying to run the audit using the tools provided by Ubuntu 22 Pro, but it always gets stuck on the same rule. Specifically, when executing the command:

`sudo usg audit cis_level1_workstation` or `sudo usg audit cis_level1_server`

It gets stuck at:

**Title User Initialization Files Must Not Run World-Writable Programs Rule xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_accounts_user_dot_no_world_writable_programs**

How can I proceed? I've tried on more than one terminal, and the same thing always happens.

Sorry if I wasn't supposed to send this here.

Thank you and in advance.

Answer (score 0):

General this remark indicates, that some configuration file has "world" rights to be written and read.
"World" right means, that everyone (user,group,others) may change that file, which implies a security risk.

Check relasted files with `ls -la`. The resulting list may look like:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Dec 15 09:59 secure.conf
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    0 Dec 15 09:58 world.conf
```

world.conf can be changed by everyone. To change those rights, the command

`chmod go-w world.conf`

would render that config file to be writeable to the owner only:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Dec 15 09:58 world.conf
```

Depending where the files are located, the command must be executed with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the command getting "stuck", it isn't. You just have to wait for it to finish.

Alternatively, you can run the command with debug:

```
sudo usg audit --debug <profile>
```

In a separate terminal, then run the following command:

```
sudo tail -f <path to results file>
```

Where  is usually /var/lib/usg/*.xml

You can see the progress being made in the output from the log being generated.

The reason for this is that it is checking MANY files and their permissions to ensure they meet the criteria. See the rationale below of the rule in question.

*If user start-up files execute world-writable programs, especially in unprotected directories, they could be maliciously modified to destroy user files or otherwise compromise the system at the user level. If the system is compromised at the user level, it is easier to elevate privileges to eventually compromise the system at the root and network level.*